# Iterations of an indirect equation using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration, equation

I am stuck on plotting a graph of surface potential(shy_s) Vs Gate voltage(vgb). I just have to solve this equation below and find the root for every iterations

```
vgb=vfb+shy_s+gama.*sqrt(shy_s+shy_t.*exp((shy_s-2.*shy_f)/shy_t))
```

where

```
shy_f=0.347; %shy_f=shy_t*ln(Na/ni)

shy_t=0.0259;   %Thermal voltage = KT/e ; where k = 1.3806*10^-23 @ 300 K       

es=11.7*8.85*10^-12; 

Na=10^10; %[unit]=[m^-3)

cox=6.93*10^-12; %[unit]=[F/m^2] and t_ox=550 A

q=1.6*10^-19;

vfb=0;

gama=(sqrt(2*q*es*Na)/cox);
```

Here I have to find the value of `shy_s(surface potential)` for different values of `vgb(gate voltage)`.

So I tried different methods to solve it, such as

```
a=zeros(1,100);

b=zeros(1,100);

for vgb=0:0.1:10

shy_s=0;

% Say 

p=shy_s;

% And

j=vgb-vfb-((sqrt(2*q*es*10^10))/cox).*sqrt(shy_s+shy_t.*exp((shy_s-2.*shy_f)/shy_t));

D=p-j;

if D>0

  for  shy_s=0:0.1:30;

    D=p-j;

    if D<0

        a=shy_s;

        break

    end

  end

elseif D<0

  for shy_s=0:0.1:30

    D=p-j;

    if D>0

        a=shy_s;

        break

    end

  end

end

b(1,vgb)=a;

end

plot(vgb,b)
```

At this manner the following error shows up:

> ??? Subscript indices
>   must either be real
>   positive integers or
>   logicals.
>
> Error in ==>
>   shy_s_vs_vgb_latest2
>   at 78
>   b(1,vgb)=a;

Again I tried to use rather a simpler technique-

```
vgb=fzero(@(shy_s)vfb+shy_s+gama.*sqrt(shy_s+shy_t.*exp((shy_s-(2.*shy_f))/shy_t)),2)
```

but it says-

> Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
>       because complex function value encountered during search.
>   (Function value at -0.56 is -0.56+62.1585i.)
>   Check function or try again with a different starting value.
>
> vgb =
>
> NaN

Another relation can be used for the same purpose

```
(vgb-vfb-shy_s)/gama)^2 = shy_s+shy_t.*(exp((shy_s-2*shy_f)/shy_y))+shy_t.*(exp(-shy_s/shy_t)-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how to use the function fzero for a simple iteration with out doing much -

for i=1:length(vgb)

c=@(shy_s)((vgb(i)-vfb-shy_s)/gama)-sqrt(abs(shy_s+shy_t.*exp((shy_s-2.*shy_f)/shy_t)));

shy_s=fzero(c,[-3 10])

a(i)=shy_s

end

- 'a' gives the correct iterated value!

Answer (score 0):

Although not likely the best solution, a quick and dirty trick is to the following:

```
opt = optimset('TolFun',1e-8);
vgb=@(shy_s) vfb+shy_s+gama.*sqrt(shy_s+shy_t.*exp((shy_s-2.*shy_f)/shy_t));
b = fminsearch(@(shy_s) abs(vgb(shy_s)-VAL),10,opt);
```

with `VAL` being the number you wish to find the inverse for.

Comment: Thx :)) ... but I am afraid i need to solve this with out using these functions for now...still at initial level so my professor asked me to solve it by using any of the iterations technique such as Newton-Raphson method or Secant method....I tried those too but somewhat similar problems showing there...

Comment: fminsearch uses an iterative algorithm: Nelder-Mead. fzero is actually far more complicated as an algorithm. Otherwise, instead of a for loop, you need to write your own `while` loop where you make sure `shy_s+shy_t.*exp((shy_s-2.*shy_f)/shy_t))` remains positive.